# How can I build an SOQL query for 3 level object?

Tags: nested, salesforce, soql

Its Master parent> child> child of object2

I just basically wanted to get all the Id and names from the Child of object2.

Tried this but I am getting 'Unknown error parsing query' SELECT Id, name (SELECT id, name FROM child of object_2) from child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completely "bottom-up"

```
SELECT Id
FROM Child2__c
WHERE Child1__r.Master__c = '...'
```

or you were close

```
SELECT Id, Name,
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Children2__r)
FROM Child1__c
WHERE Master__c = '...'
```

(but for this you'll have to be sure what's the relationship name between child1 and 2)

## Edit after OP provided exact relationship names

**Bottom up** would be

```soql
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Event_Expense_Detail__c
WHERE Service_Order__r.Ford_Field_Event__c = 'one master id goes here'
```

You start from the lowest point (detail) then go "up" with dot notation once to Event Expense and then "up" again. If you still don't feel it - try

```soql
SELECT 
    Service_Order__r.Ford_Field_Event__r.Id, Service_Order__r.Ford_Field_Event__r.Name,
    Service_Order__r.Id, Service_Order__r.Name,
    Id, Name
FROM Event_Expense_Detail__c 
ORDER BY Service_Order__r.Ford_Field_Event__r.Name, Service_Order__r.Name, Name
LIMIT 100
```

**Top-down** is limited, you can go 1 level down. So we'd have

```soql
SELECT 
    Ford_Field_Event__r.Id, Ford_Field_Event__r.Name,
    Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Service_Order_Items__r)
FROM Event_Expense__c
WHERE Ford_Field_Event__c = 'one master id goes here'
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, unfortunately, I got this error: 

(SELECT Id, Name FROM Event_Expense_Detail__r)
                      ^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:23
Didn't understand relationship 'Event_Expense_Detail__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: These are their relationship:

Master = Ford_Field_Event__c

Child1 = Event_Expense__c
Ford_Field_Event__c Master-Detail(Ford Field Event)

child2 = Event_Expense_Detail__c

I notice one common field =  CreatedById Lookup(User)

Comment: These are field names, not "relationship names" (which are kind of table aliases if you'd be making JOINs in a normal database). Go to SF setup -> object manager -> Event_Expense_Detail__c  -> fields. Find the lookup (probably Ford_Field_Event__c), write the "child relationship name" down and mentally add __r at the end. If it's `abc` - check if `select id, name, (select id, name from abc__r) from Ford_Field_Event__c limit 5` is a valid query.

Comment: the query select id, name, (select id, name from abc__r) from Ford_Field_Event__c limit 5 is not working for me. here are their relationship: https://app.screencast.com/RZMKPwo0ZqoXZ https://app.screencast.com/AvuDaNP2h1fzz https://app.screencast.com/E9ddiGwD4nlrX

Comment: That helps but it's not exactly "it". I'm after "child relationship name", what's on first screenshot in https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/relationship-query-apex-salesforce/. Go to Event Expense, click "Ford Field Event", write down the child relationship name. Go to Event Expense Detail, click Service Order, write down the child relationship name.

Comment: https://app.screencast.com/WKSoP8v3v1A2T

Child Relationship Name Service_Orders


https://app.screencast.com/UbW3JV8KYqaTS

Child Relationship Name Service_Order_Items

now I'm confused, I think I was trying to use a different field that doesn't have a relationship.

Comment: OMG it works, I now know where to look precisely when checking the relationship, thank you so much!!!